# Getting Error from DateTime is there a bug in it in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, cron

I'm getting the following error coming from Cron every time it runs my code and it looks like it is coming from DateTime is there a bug in DateTime or am I not using it correctly.
Line 24 in the error is this:-

```
$date = new DateTime($datetrue);
```

and what I am giving DateTime in $datetrue is 2014-06-13 13:00:00

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'Exception' with message 'DateTime::__construct(): Failed to parse time string (2014-06-13 25:30:00) at position 11 (2): Unexpected character' in /home3/rdkurth/public_html/cron.php:24
>
> Stack trace:
>
> #0 /home3/rdkurth/public_html/cron.php(24): DateTime->__construct('2014-06-13 25:3...')
>      #1 {main}
>      thrown in /home3/rdkurth/public_html/cron.php on line 24`

My code:-

```
require_once("connect.php");
require_once ("function.php");
$sql = "Select
  signings.id,         
  signings.pid,
  signings.signstart,
  signings.starttime,
  remindertime.rtime,
  signings.done
From
  signings Inner Join
  profile On profile.id = signings.pid Inner Join
  remindertime On profile.emailrt = remindertime.rtid
Where
  signings.pid = 7 And
  signings.signstart = CurDate() And
  signings.done = 0";
foreach ($db->query($sql) as $signings)
 {
$signingid = $signings['id'];    
$newsub= '- ' . $signings['rtime']; // the time that needs to subtracted from the scheduled date
$datetrue =$signings['signstart'] . ' ' . $signings['starttime']; //The schedule appontment time
$date = new DateTime($datetrue);
$date = date_modify($date, $newsub);
$senddate = date_format($date, 'Y-m-d H:i'); //the date to send the remider
if ($senddate == date('Y-m-d H:i')) {

//get all the customers data to put in the message
```

Comment: 25:30:00 is not a valid time, it starts from 00:00:00 to 23:59:59 on a given date

Comment: He said the value he's passing is 2014-06-13 13:00:00.

Comment: The error shows `2014-06-13 25:3...`

Comment: Yup, sounds like misdiagnosis to me.

Answer (score -1):

1. Try using strtotime() directly. My experience with the DateTime class is that is does not always behave as expected and documented. In Addition, if you look into php's documentation on the class there is a lot of change across different php versions.
2. My second advice is to define a common time zone for your application system. You are comparing data taken from a database with time values generated by your php application. Unless you set the time Zone explicitly you may run into issues at some point.
   Refer to https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-default-timezone-set.php
3. Third advice: Never do operations that may fail in construct statements. When using explicit (member) functions you get better error responses in most cases. In fact, exception handling should always be the last line of defence - do not consider your code to be complete unless you implemented procedural error handling!

Comment: I created a function using strtotime but I don't understand how I can add time zone to my script. The program will be used all over the United States so I a lot of different time zones. I don't understand how to implicate a common time zone.

Comment: Hear is the function I created                                            function getsendtime($datetrue,$newsub){
$datetime = strtotime($datetrue);
$startTime = date("Y-m-d H:i", strtotime($newsub, $datetime));
return $startTime;
}

Comment: I don't understand your third advice

Comment: `"My experience with the DateTime class is that is does not always behave as expected and documented."`. That isn't my experience, quite the opposite and I use it extensively. Perhaps you are using it wrong?

Comment: Re 2: Time zones: users are in different time zones. So depending on their physical location they may want to have time and date Information to be displayed in their own time zone. But when you store time and date information in a database or measure time on your servers (e.g. using time()) you have to make a decision to which timezone you normalize this data.

Comment: Or in other words: the time zone should be an aspect of user specific visualization - in a database all date and time information should be relating to one time zone.

Comment: Re 3: When contructing a class the result value is the class itself - or null - but not an error code to which you can react in an organized controlled way. All I am saying is, contruct the class without parameters and use the member function to fill it with data. At least for debugging.